# springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() returning error No such property: id for class: java.lang.String

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have tried to add this code to the `AdminLoginController` to check the current user's Role.

```
def checkRole() {

        User user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()

        if(User.getRoleByUser(user.username).contains(Constants.ROLE_ADMIN)){
            redirect uri:'/admin'
        }else if(User.getRoleByUser(user.username).contains(Constants.ROLE_TWO)) {
            redirect uri:'/two'
        }else if(User.getRoleByUSer(user.username).contains(Constants.ROLE_THREE)){
            redirect uri: '/three'
        }else{

        }   
    }
```

When I try to run the application it's showing the error below:

```
 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: java.lang.String
```

The error is on the line `User user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()`

Comment: have u injected springSecurityService into your controller:
like this :    def springSecurityService

Comment: yes i did. i couldn't forget that.

Comment: @Joshua Moore thank you for the correction. now can you give me some idea how to solve it.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I do this: def springSecuirtyService and I have all the security stuff working, but still no luck. If I put the call and def in a service, it works, but if I try to do it in a controller, get this error.  No solution found.

Comment: @JohnLittle checkout my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {

        User user = securityService.getCurrentUser()  //Note:- i used securityService not springSecurityService 

        List<Role> currentUserRoles = UserRole.findByUser(user).collect { it.role } as List

        if(currentUserRoles.contains(Role.findByName(Constants.ROLE_ONE))) {

            redirect(controller:'admin', action:'index')

        } else if(currentUserRoles.contains(Role.findByName(Constants.ROLE_TWO))) {

            redirect(controller:'two', action:'action')

        } else if(currentUserRoles.contains(Role.findByName(Constants.ROLE_THREE))) {

            redirect(controller:'three', action:'action')
        }

    } else {

        redirect action: 'auth', params: params
    }
}
```

Note:- userRole domain class links role and the user.